# Mule ESB standalone encoding corruption

Tags: java, encoding, mule, activemq-classic

I have a situation in Mule ESB where I am sending in messages on a ActiveMQ through the interactive console, these messages are encoded in utf-8. But when I try to send the same messages in on a restricted server with a mule standalone enterprise edition, the encoding of the messages are corrupted and no longer utf-8. Is this because of a configuration setting of the standalone server that has to be set or?

We are using

- Mule Runtime 3.7.0
- Java Compiler 1.7 jdk 1.7.0_79
- ActiveMQ 5.11.1
- Windows Server 2012 R2

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the default encoding of your platform, that is Windows Server. The default encoding might be ISO-8859-1. Mule ESB normally sits on the platform encoding.

In addition, you could force the Encoding of your IDE Anypoint Studio to debug your project, check [this](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2FwrkAdv_encoding.htm)

In your flow, you could try to add the encoding manually

```
<byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String" encoding="UTF-16"/>
```

Check [this link](https://www.ricston.com/blog/string-encoding-mule/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the hint Tony K, but i had already tried that. I found out what the problem was. I had defined `wrapper.java.additional.14=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 and wrapper.java.additional.15=-Dmule.encoding=UTF-8` in the  wrapper.config file of mule-standalone, but it was not enough to just restart the service, I had to reinstall the service before it was affected by the changes.